# List: Counting and Deleting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list, for example List=["X","X","O","O",'O','O'], how would I count how many "X"'s there are in a list, and then subtract that many "O"s from the list. The List will always put all X's first and all O's last. I thought I could do something like...

```
List=["X","X","O","O",'O','O']
ListCount=List.count("X")
del List[-(List2):0]
```

I thought this would yield ["X","X","O","O"] by deleting the O's from -2:0   but absolutely nothing happened. In python.

Comment: It's worth noting, if you don't care about order (which, as you have said they will always be in the same order, must be true), why not just store the number of each, which makes this trivial?

Comment: just a quibble (I don't remember if it's in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but it should be), but try to avoid naming variables for built-ins, even if you're changing the capitalization. Instead of `List`, try `my_list` or `first_list` or something like that. That way a minor capitalization typo later won't give you strange behavior, like overwriting built-in functions.

Comment: @MattDMo It is in PEP-8 - `CapWords` is reserved for class names. This is really worth following as it makes code much more readable - heck, even SO uses it to highlight your code - it presumes anything in `CapWords` is a class and highlights it light blue.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in my comment, another data structure could be more useful here, as you don't care about order:

```
data = {"X": 2, "O": 4}
data["O"] -= data["X"]
```

If you ever need the actual list, it's easy to create with a quick [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
data_list = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(key, count) for key, count in data.items()))
```

Or, to go the other way:

```
from collections import Counter
data = Counter(data_list)
```

Comment: If the data is originally in list form, convert to counts by doing `collections.Counter[original_list]`.

Answer (score 1):

The index zero corresponds to the first item in a list, so your slice `List[-2:0]` says to go from the next to last to just before the first. Since that's going to be an empty range, you don't get anything from your slice (or rather, your `del` statement doesn't delete anything).

Instead, leave out the second part of the slice. Python will slice to the end of the list automatically.

```
del List[-ListCount:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, your slicing should look like this:

```
del List[-ListCount:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way seems to work - you shouldn't use List2 bu ListCount in your example. Maybe it's not too pythonic, and it will work only within conditions that you stated but it works :)

```
>>> l = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
>>> del l[-l.count(1):]
>>> print l
[1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
List = ["X","X","O","O",'O','O']
xCount = List.count('X')
List = List[:-xCount]
```